# Is it possible to aggregate stackexchange profiles of all people in a company?

Tags: discussion

We are building a new company website. We are a small startup with most people active on SO. We would like to put an aggregated view of the SO profile plugin with points badges etc. is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Visit your Stack Overflow profile.

There is a tab called *flair*, where you can export a small badge with your user avatar, the cumulated reputation and badges as well as logos of the sites you're on.

[image: profile for slhck on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

For you, that'd look like so:

[image: profile for 240300 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

You can also export your *flair* for just Stack Overflow, and with various color themes.

Comment: The Flair is for an individual, what I am looking for is something like the flair which aggregates my team's SE contributions.

Comment: There's no such thing. You could put all flairs next to each other or, of course, roll your own solution with the [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).